# Top down slider

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit

I am using XCode 6.1.1 on OSX 10.10

I have a following Cocoa Window

[image: Cocoa Window]

I am not able to make a vertical top down slider using IB only. (Second slider in B view)
As in the example

- For horizontal slider it works fine when I set the other slider's layout to "Right to left". (As seen in A view)
- But for the vertical slider when I set it to "Right to left" slider it is not working the other ways. (As seen in B view).
- I also tried using setFrameCenterRotation, it solves the purpose but the autoalyout gets messed up. (As seen C view)

  It seems to be an XCode bug.

---

So how do I make a top down slider using IB only ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a bug. The layout direction is used to mirror controls in right-to-left interfaces. Therefore, the vertical slider will look the same for both layouts.

You may be able to subclass the slider to change his appearance manually.